# What place in a car is regarded as a visible place for all passengers?

Tags: california, driving

I read on http://allucam.com/legality-dash-cam/:

> Dash cameras obviously can make a visual record of the road ahead, but under state law, they must also be capable of recording and saving audio data. **Because this requirement raises privacy concerns, you must post a notice in a visible place in your car that notifies passengers that their conversations are being recorded**. The owner or lessee of the vehicle can turn the device off at any time. The information stored on the recorder belongs to the owner as a matter of law.

This state law is [V C Section 26708 Material Obstructing or Reducing Driver x2019 s View](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/vctop/vc/d12/c4/26708):

> (B) A vehicle equipped with a video event recorder shall have a notice posted in a visible location which states that a passenger's conversation may be recorded.

What place(s) in the car is regarded as a visible place for all passengers, how to assess whether the font is large enough, and how about visually impaired passenger?

Comment: @nomenagentis I don't know, I couldn't find. I added the state law stipulating a notice has to be displayed.

Comment: Why have just one place, instead of putting multiple notices?

Comment: @cpast One place is annoying enough. The law just asks for one. Let's keep it minimal.

Answer (score 5):

The statute in question is section [26708 (13)(B)](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=26001-27000&file=26700-26712):

> A vehicle equipped with a video event recorder shall have a
>   notice posted in a visible location which states that a passenger's
>   conversation may be recorded.

It doesn't require it be visible to *all* passengers and doesn't make any provision for visually impaired passengers.

I am not licenced to practice in California but know of no cases clarifying how "visible" the notice needs to be. I wouldn't suggest trying to hide the notice, though.

Comment: Good point, the law fails to explicitly states to whom the notification should be visible.

Answer (score -1):

Like Nomen said, the law fails to point out who exactly needs to see it.  But in the interest of *actually answering the question*, I would say there a few places you could post such a notice:

1. On the dash (most people take a look at the center of the dash - usually to look at the clock)
2. post the notice on their seat (yes they're sitting on it, but then they have to see it)
3. The law doesn't say it has to be *in* the vehicle, so you could simple post it on the door, or the bumper or somewhere conspicuous outside.
4. Hang a sheet of paper from the ceiling (so that it's hanging down flapping around - hard to miss)

Basically think of anywhere where that you look at regularly as a passenger.